# Hide Worksheet on the basis of the ending part of their name - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large number of worksheets inside my workbook. I only need to make worksheets that has the name "Main" and tabs that are ending with "_Summary".

[ Note the Underscore before the Summary ]

I tried a basic logic before going to the tough part , just to hide the Main worksheet and another worksheet that has the name Monthly_Summary. I Could get it done for this logic but how to generalize it to check it for sheets ending with _Summary. Here is the Code,

```
Sub tabopen()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet

    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count

                Workseetname = Worksheets(i).Name

                If (Workseetname = "Main" Or Workseetname = "Monthly_Summary") Then
                    Sheets(Workseetname).Visible = True
                Else
                    Sheets(Workseetname).Visible = False
                End If
    Next i


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Please advise and share your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without testing I think you need this edit: `If Worksheets(i).Name <> "Main" Or Worksheets(i).Name <> "Monthly_Summary" Then`

Comment: @mrbungle No tried that as well..It didn't work

Comment: Note you have a typo, `Workseetname`. Should it be `Worksheetname`? Also, you declare `ws` but never use it. Also are you getting any errors?  Also if you want to *hide* `Main` and `Monthly_Summary`, shouldn't the logic be `If Worksheets(i).Name = "Main" or Worksheets(i).Name = "Monthly_Summary"`?

Comment: @BruceWayne yes, you were right. I just got that and updated the question. Now, how should I generalize to enable all sheets that ends with _Summary and as well as Main sheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hide the "Main" and "*_Summary" worksheets:

```
Sub tabopen()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count    
        Worksheets(i).Visible = Not (Worksheets(i).Name = "Main" Or _
                                     Worksheets(i).Name Like "*_Summary")
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Sir. But it doesn't require the not because it does the exact opposite. Thanks again for the logic :)

Comment: @Sid29 Without the `Not`, the "Main" and "*_Summary" sheets will be `Visible` and all the others will be hidden.  Which is the exact opposite to what you ask for in the title ("Hide Worksheet on the basis of the ending part of their name - VBA") and in the question ("just to hide the Main worksheet and another worksheet that has the name Monthly_Summary").  So I think you do want the `Not`.

Comment: Man, that's pretty snazzy the way you do the `.Visible = Not(...)`. I really need to think more like that with `TRUE`/`FALSE` settings.

Answer (score 1):

The logical part wasn't quite right.  Here is a version which is easy to step through:

```
Sub tabopen()
    Dim Worksheetname As String, i As Integer, shouldBeVisible As Boolean
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Worksheetname = Worksheets(i).Name
        shouldBeVisible = Worksheets(i).Name = "Main" Or Right(Worksheets(i).Name, 8) = "_Summary"
        Sheets(Worksheetname).Visible = shouldBeVisible
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've done lots and lots of sheets deletes and creations of new sheets (especially if there were charts as new sheets involved), I wouldn't trust going through the Worksheets by the index, since it is a collection.
I had issues of Excel crashing on me back in 2002 trying to refer to a Worksheet(i).Name; Excel simply couldn't find the index.
I know Excel had changed since then.
Either way, this is the "safer" way to iterate through the worksheets:

```
Sub mySub()
    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet    
    For Each Sh1 In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Sh1.Visible = Not (Sh1.Name = "Main" Or Sh1.Name Like "*_Summary")
    Next
End Sub
```